# prevent over writing data in hash

Tags: perl

I have data.txt with data as shown below. I have around hundred names with 3 constant ids 100, 200, 300 and each have 32 data values.

```
NAME: xyz
ID: 100
DATA: 10 15 99 13 ...
ID: 200
DATA: 23 45 78 90..
ID: 300
DATA: 45 67 89 56
NAME: abc
ID: 100
DATA: 2 4 787 8..
ID: 200
DATA: 12 14 17..
ID: 300
DATA: 45 34 22..
```

I need to write this data to another file which looks like

```
xyz_100, xyz_200,xyz_300,abc_100,...
10     , 23     , 45     ,2
15     , 45     ,67       ,4
```

I build a hash to store the values, but right now my code overwrites the first two entries and store the last entry. How can I save the first two entries too, please let me know if I can simplify the code.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use diagnostics;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @avar_names;
my %record;

local $/ = '';
open my $fh, '<', 'datalog.dat' or die "failed: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
   my %avar;
   while (/^([A-Z:]+):\s*(.*)/mg) {
      $avar{$1} = $2;
   }
   my $avar_name = "$avar{NAME}_$avar{ID}";

   push @avar_names, $avar_name;
   $record{$avar_name} = $avar{DATA};

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%record;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a consistency problem: the `local` line makes the first *while* process the whole NAME/ID data as a whole (then, thanks to the `while(//mg)` loop), but the code as it is expects a line by line processing.

I suggest simplicity: process the file lines one by one, for each one, identify a "NAME/ID" couple (ID could be DATA) thanks to a regex on the current line.

In order for that to work, `%avar` needs *not* to be local to the `while` on `<$fh>`, since it has to keep track of the last NAME/ID reference it got from the last lines of the file.

The `@avar_names` array is not used.

Finally, you want to print the resulting records at the end (I supposed), but that is your choice.

This is your program from which I tried to change only the things mentioned above:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use diagnostics;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @avar_names;
my %record;

#local $/ = ''; ## commented out
open my $fh, '<', 'datalog.dat' or die "failed: $!";

my %avar; ## moved here

while (<$fh>) {
   chomp;
   if (m/^([A-Z]+):\s*(.*)/) {  ## if, not a while
      $avar{$1} = $2;

      ## ensure we have at least our 3 keys, process only if we met DATA
      if (exists($avar{NAME}) && exists($avar{ID}) && exists($avar{DATA}) && $1 eq 'DATA') { 
         my $avar_name = "$avar{NAME}_$avar{ID}";

         push @avar_names, $avar_name;  ## not used
         $record{$avar_name} = $avar{DATA};
      }
   }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%record;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'xyz_100' => '10 15 99 13 ...',
          'xyz_300' => '45 67 89 56',
          'abc_200' => '12 14 17..',
          'abc_300' => '45 34 22..',
          'abc_100' => '2 4 787 8..',
          'xyz_200' => '23 45 78 90..'
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Dump is not printing anything. is the value of %record out of the scope? if I change to print \%avar instead of \%record its printing the last value abc_300.

Comment: Oops. it is actually `$1`, not `$2` in the `if (exists ...)` line... Should always trust a copy paste vs manual change ;-)

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to do that. I will definitely once I get a chance. could you explain in brief why its printing xyz_100,_300,abc_200 so on.. even we are reading in an orderly manner? is it because of $avar{1}=$2 ??

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
my @avars;
# ... some code
while (<$fh>) {
  # more code
  my %curr;
  while (/^([A-Z:]+):\s*(.*)/mg) {
    $curr->{$1} = $2;
  }
  if (%curr) {
     push @avars, \%curr;
     my $avar_name = "$curr{NAME}_$curr{ID}";
     push @avar_names, $avar_name;
     $record{$avar_name} = $avar{DATA};
  }
  # ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. do you mean @avars or %avars? can I address a negative value to array?$avars[-1]??

Comment: I mean @avars, you can use `-1` to refer to the last (pushed) item

Comment: error shows: Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -1 at script3.pl
        line 18, <$fh> chunk 1 (#1)
    (F) You tried to make an array value spring into existence, and the
    subscript was probably negative, even counting from end of the array
    backwards.